# Facehugger-animal offspring

Tags: alien-franchise, hybrid

In the movies you only ever see eggs lain in humans and one predator. So theorectically could a facehugger latch onto a cat or a zoo animal? Is there any particular reason why they couldn't? And finally would it look different than a normal human-alien offspring similar to how the alien-predator creature was different?

Comment: Did you purposefully "forget" Alien3?

Comment: I actually don't think i saw that one. I've only seen Alien, Aliens, AvP, Avp 2, and Avp Requiem.

Comment: @Erratak: [AVP Requiem *is* AVP2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens_vs._Predator:_Requiem).

Comment: I only consider the first two movies to be canon, but even within that frame of reference it's quite obvious that they'd be able to parasitize anything of sufficient size. Large dogs, certainly anything bigger. Probably not a house cat. And not just Earth animals, these things could probably parasitize organisms no matter how exotic their biology is.

Comment: cats are explicitly stated to be too small to be a host in promethus

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [Alien<sup>3</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_3) the xenomorph is implanted into a dog, and as you suspected the resulting alien different from the human-form variety. Although still the same general human shape, it moves in a much more animalistic fashion.

Comment: I watched Alien3 but it was an ox

Answer (score 1):

You can also state the following:
A facehugger can put an embryo into everything, though uncertain it will succeed.
The form of the alien depends of the skeletal structure of the host:

- A biped, like a human, will become a bipedal alien capable of walking straight.
- A quadruped, like an ox, will become a four legged alien, probably not able to stand up.
- Though unlikely a facehugger would ever jump onto a shark, the alien would become shark shaped, maybe with a much wider head.

(I also should note that during the 90's there were non-canon toys of

1. a rhino, with a much bigger body and a horn on its head.
2. a bull, who's body was like a bull including two horns,
3. I had a toy from a bat which had big wings.)